# Html text input date mask using php

Tags: php, regex, date, mask

Is it possible to apply a date mask to a html text input using a regular expression or something? I want a text input to accept only numbers in the format of: dd/mm/yyyy

I've only found examples using javascript, not php.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, PHP is server-side language. You'll need to use javascript for this.